# Featherjs and Angular 2 error

Tags: angular2-services, feathersjs

im trying to use FeathersJS with Angular 2 but i can't get it to work, im following the guide here: [Angular2 Guide with Feathers](https://legacy.docs.feathersjs.com/frameworks/angular2.html)
My problem is that i create the services as it says like this:

```
import * as feathers from 'feathers/client';
import * as hooks from 'feathers-hooks';
import * as rest from 'feathers-rest/client';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const superagent = require('superagent');

const HOST = 'https://myurl.com/';

@Injectable()
export class RestService {
  private _app: any;
  constructor() {
    this._app = feathers() // Initialize feathers
      .configure(rest(HOST).superagent(superagent)) // Fire up rest
      .configure(hooks()); // Configure feathers-hooks
  }
}
```

And i try to use it like this

```
import { RestService } from './rest.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  private _rest;

  constructor( private _restService: RestService ) {
    this._rest = _restService.getService('users');
  }

}
```

And i get the error: "Property 'getService' does not exist on type 'RestService'"

I think i have to instantiate the service but i can get it to do it, any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I use with the last version 3.0.1, and install with those commands:

```
npm install @feathersjs/feathers @feathersjs/socketio-client --save
npm install @feathersjs/authentication-client --save
npm install socket.io-client --save
```

In Angular 4, my service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import socketio from '@feathersjs/socketio-client';
import authencl from '@feathersjs/authentication-client';

import io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  private urlServer = 'http://localhost:3030';
  private socket = io(this.urlServer, {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    forceNew: true
  });

  app: any;

  constructor() {
    this.app = feathers()
        .configure(socketio(this.socket))
        .configure(authencl());
  }
}
```